# InfoPath repeating section missing fields

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I have a repeating section in infopath with a 3x3 table inside of it populated with textboxes. When I view the preview about half of the cells are missing from the table. I'm wondering if anyone has ever had this problem or knows how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be default value settings. There are two places you can check whether fields are included by default.

1. Data tab in the ribbon, find the Default Values button. Expand schema nodes until you find the missing fields - make sure they are checked.
2. Repeating table defaults, right click the repeating table and under properties, click on the edit defaults button, make sure that the fields are included.

This can also happen if you have added fields and are opening a previously filled out form and the form is not set to upgrade existing XML. However, since you say this is happening in preview, I anticipate this is not your issue, unless you are previewing with existing XML and the form is not set to upgrade.